# Bag of LEGO pieces that I don't know - lots of earth tones, some black and grey

Tags: set-identification

Do you guys know what these LEGO pieces are? Please tell me.

[image: Lego]

Answer (score 13):

Based on

- [Sand Green Arch 1 x 3 x 2 Curved Top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6005)
- [Dark Tan Brick 2 x 4](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3001)

The only set on BrickLink with both of these seems to be [75318-1](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=75318-1) The Child

[image: 75138]

Comment: Note that there are also pieces in that pile that do not belong to set 75318, like the foliage piece in the top right corner. No guarantees that this is indeed the complete set.

Comment: At least what's pictured, it's definitely not the complete set. I've got this particular set and there's 8+ bags in total and a number of the bricks shown are not part of it.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas does this set have any red? That's the biggest differentiator I see in OPs image that makes me think it's not The Child set...

Comment: Only one other set (7572) has at least 6 Dark Tan 8x8 plates, and it doesn't look anything like this.

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes, there's some red pieces; they're structural bits buried deep inside the model. Confused me why they were so outside of the color palette when i was building it. The main thing that sticks out as not being part of the set is that weird green leaf-like piece top right.